# Which filters can be used together in git-filter-branch?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

`git-filter-branch` has `--env-filter`, `--tree-filter`, `--index-filter`, `--parent-filter`, `--msg-filter`, `--commit-filter`, `--tag-name-filter`, etc.

Can all of these be used together, or are some mutatually exclusive? For example, if I want to adjust the index and change committers, can I use `--index-filter` and `--env-filter` on the same run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can in fact all be used together.  The only thing not allowed is an attempt to set both `--prune-empty` *and* a `--commit-filter` (because `--prune-empty` is implemented *as* a commit filter, specifically, a filter of `git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@"`).